# Testing Login with Model Mommy

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests, model-mommy

I having a problem testing my login  in my functional test. I am using model mommy to create a a user call Megan with a password, but my test still does not pass since when the information is sent it throws up and error on the html page of "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." So I suspect that the test user is not being created or something like that.

functional_test:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from model_mommy import mommy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class NewUserTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = mommy.make('User', 
        username='Megan',
        password = 'password',
        is_active = True)

        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_user_can_start_a_new_movement(self):
        #some code
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertIn('P2', self.browser.title)

        #Megan first logs in 
        login_link = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Log In')
        login_link.click()
        #Megan then puts in her user information
        username = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_username')
        password = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_password')
        submit = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_submit')
        username.send_keys('Megan')
        password.send_keys('password')
        submit.click()
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}

<form action="/accounts/login/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="submit" id='id_submit'>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

users.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

from movements import views 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', login,
 {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code is not working at the moment because `mommy.make` is not hashing the password. I don't see any advantage of using `mommy` in this case, so it should be fine to use the regular [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method instead.

```
self.user = User.objects.create_user 
    username='Megan',
    email='megan@example.com',
    password = 'password',
)
```

This will ensure that the password is hashed properly.

If you still want to use model mommy so that it creates foreign keys to other models, you can call [`set_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) to correctly hash the password. Thanks mislavcimpersak for suggesting this in their answer.

```
    self.user = mommy.make('User', 
    username='Megan',
    is_active = True)
    self.user.set_password('password')
    self.save()
```

Comment: model_mommy deals with creation of any number of related and other fields that may not be visible (or could have been removed from the above canonical example) here. Hopefully this has worked for the OP, but the general answer using model_mommy is given by @mislavcimpersak

Comment: Yeah, fair point. OK I'll neutralise my down vote when SO lets me but still feel like this doesn't answer the question, which seems to be "how can I do this with model_mommy".

Answer (score 6):

if you still insist on using model mommy:

```
class NewUserTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = mommy.make('User', 
            username='Megan',
            is_active = True)
        self.user.set_password('password')
        self.user.save()
```